# Rails 4 app visually different between development and production

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, centos6

I have a Rails 4 app deployed on a Centos machine. Although everything seems to work fine it looks slightly different to my development instance in that everything is a little wider and fonts etc are a little less sharp. There doesn't seem to be any issues with any of the assets - when I use chrome development tools there are no errors showing for example and when I compare by 'inspect element' on the css both instances are exactly the same. The only difference I see is that the body width on the production is wider than on the development (on my current screen 2114px vs 1903px). The app uses bootstrap 3 and has a custom theme loaded in, and as I say, they all seem to migrate across fine to the production instance.

I'm not really sure where to look at this point for where the difference is being caused (nor what files to provide as way of help) but I would really like to fix this as the production version looks that little bit clumsy. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a link to the production version of the site? I want to see how all your custom stylesheets are being loaded after your bootstrap library.

Comment: The production site is here: https://hie-sampletracker.uws.edu.au/ (you'll have to ignore the SSL cert for now until I get round to putting that in). Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your stylesheets are rendering in this order:
Jquery UI -> Bootstrap 3.2 -> Bootswatch 3.2 -> Jasney Bootstrap 3.1

Your custom Bootswatch theme has a different default body font(Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif) than the traditional bootstrap sans serif font ("Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif) which is overriding you Bootstrap and making the fonts look like print style fonts.

The same is happening to your default .container class. The custom bootswatch .container width is larger  then the default bootstrap .container class.

My guess is your bootswatch library isn't loading on your local machine or loading before bootstrap. So you're seeing all the default bootstrap themes instead(which look better in my opinion). Then when you push to production the bootswatch theme is being loaded after bootstrap and hence overriding all the nice bootstrap defaults you see on your local machine.

If you're still having issue with the order they are loading, try creating a css manifest file in your application/stylesheets, move(if they aren't there already) all your css libraries to vendor/assets/stylesheets in separate files and call those files in your manifest file using this convention:

```
/*
*= require jqueryui
*= require bootstrap
*= require bootswatch
*= require jasney
*/
```

This way you can manually order which assets are precompiled. They will compile top to bottom, in the exact order you include them in this stylesheet. **Make sure to include you manifest sheet at the top of you view or your application/views/layouts/application.html.erb file. (You may have to adjust your production.rb file too)

There's a couple idea, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's a detailed answer. I looked at my stuff in more detail and have realised that the production version is more 'correct' - if I compare it with the bootstrap theme page itself [link](http://bootswatch.com/readable/) you can see that everything matches up. It's the dev version which is slightly off. However I already have my manifest file set up the way you state (and is in that same order). 

Both Production and my local Dev version show (using chrome inspect): 
`media="all"
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
width: 1170px;
}`
and all other elements appear to match.

Comment: Good stuff! Sounds like everything was setup properly!

Comment: (ran out of characters on my comment above). Just to add that I'll have a look in more detail at my dev version and see if I can find what isn't loading/missing. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know if I find anything